# Yolov3 don't detect anything but Yolov2 works fine

Tags: java, opencv, yolo

The aim of my application is to detect humans. If I'm loading YOLOv2 weights and config, everything works great. If I'm loading YOLOv3 weights and config, net returns 0 on all class confidences on all bounding boxes. I tried both normal YOLOv3-416 and YOLOv3-tiny from https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/. As far as I know requered input and outputs on YOLOv2 and YOLOv3 are identical. Please help me find what I made wrong that YOLOv3 don't work. I'm using OpenCV 4.01 and Java wrapper for it. I'm using only CPU. I tried to find similar problem but I didn't find anything similar.

```
public class YoloAnalizer {
private Net net;
private StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

private final double threshold = 0.5;
private final double scaleFactor = 1.0 / 255.000;
private final Size imageSize = new Size(416, 416);
private final Scalar mean = new Scalar(0,0,0);
private final boolean swapRB = true;
private final boolean crop = false;

private final String[] classes = new String[] {"person", "bicycle", "car", "motorcycle",
                                             "airplane", "bus", "train", "truck", "boat", "traffic light", "fire hydrant",
                                             "stop sign", "parking meter", "bench", "bird", "cat", "dog", "horse",
                                             "sheep", "cow", "elephant", "bear", "zebra", "giraffe", "backpack",
                                             "umbrella", "handbag", "tie", "suitcase", "frisbee", "skis",
                                             "snowboard", "sports ball", "kite", "baseball bat", "baseball glove", "skateboard",
                                             "surfboard", "tennis racket", "bottle", "wine glass", "cup", "fork", "knife",
                                             "spoon", "bowl", "banana", "apple", "sandwich", "orange", "broccoli", "carrot", "hot dog",
                                             "pizza", "donut", "cake", "chair", "couch", "potted plant", "bed", "dining table",
                                             "toilet", "tv", "laptop", "mouse", "remote", "keyboard",
                                             "cell phone", "microwave", "oven", "toaster", "sink", "refrigerator",
                                 "book", "clock", "vase", "scissors", "teddy bear", "hair drier", "toothbrush"};

public YoloAnalizer(String pathToYoloDarknetConfig, String pathToYoloDarknetWeights) {
    net = Dnn.readNetFromDarknet(pathToYoloDarknetConfig, pathToYoloDarknetWeights);
}

public List<Rect> AnalizeImage(Mat image) {
    logger.debug("Starting analisic image using yolo");
    stopWatch.StartTime();
    Mat blob = Dnn.blobFromImage(image, scaleFactor, imageSize, mean, swapRB, crop);
    net.setInput(blob);

    Mat prediction = net.forward();
    List<Rect> rects = ConvertPredictionToRoundingBox(prediction, image);
    logger.debug(String.format("Analising frame took: %s", stopWatch.GetElapsedMiliseconds()));
    return rects;
}

private List<Rect> ConvertPredictionToRoundingBox(Mat prediction, Mat image) {
    List<Rect> listOfPredictedObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < prediction.size().height; i++) {
        float[] row = new float[85];
        prediction.get(i, 0, row);

        float confidenceOnBox = row[4];
        int predictedClassConfidence = getTableIndexWithMaxValue(row, 5);
        double score = confidenceOnBox * row[predictedClassConfidence];
        if (score > threshold) {
            double x_center   = row[0] * image.width();
            double y_center   = row[1] * image.height();
            double width = row[2] * image.width();
            double height = row[3] * image.height();

            double left  = x_center - width * 0.5;
            double top  = y_center - height * 0.5;

            listOfPredictedObjects.add(new Rect((int)left, (int)top, (int)width, (int)height));
            logger.info(String.format("Found %s(%s) with confidence %s", classes[predictedClassConfidence-5],predictedClassConfidence, score));
        }
    }
    return listOfPredictedObjects;
}

private int getTableIndexWithMaxValue(float[] array, int startFrom) {
    double maxValue = -1;
    int maxIndex = -1;
    for (int i = startFrom; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (maxValue < array[i]) {
            maxIndex = i;
            maxValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I discovered in v3:

In the function `fill_truth_region`:

The truth table is created with format "1-classes-x-y-w-h", i.e. each entry in the truth table is 1+number of classes+4.

But in the `forward_yolo_layer` function it seems getting box truth will take
x,y,w,h from the beginning of the entry, which seems to be getting 1 for x if there is an entry and then the portion of classes into y,w,h.

I think if you change this in `forward_yolo_layer`:

```
box truth=float_to_box(net.truth + t * 5 + b * l.truths, 1);
```

to this:

```
box truth=float_to_box(net.truth + t * (5+l.classes) + b * l.truths + l.classes+1, 1);
```

then you will get a truth box with the correct x,y,w,h.